# Program occurrences that counts digits, white spaces and other stuff what's best,average and worst case

Tags: c

```
main() 
{
    int c, i , nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];
    
    nwhite = nother = 0;
    
    for(i = 0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        ndigit[i] = 0;
    }
    
    while((c = my_getchar(ndigit,nwhite,nother)) != EOF)
        if(c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;
            
    
}
```

so this is code from book, what's the best, average and worst case for increment itterations. for best case I realized that it's O(1) like when you have one input you always get only one increment but how about worst and average cases I am getting confused. Like whats worst and average case for increment operations in this code as you see ++ndigit, ++nwhite and ++nother are increment operations and I am wondering am I correct about best case? I would like to get little help with best average and worst cases for this increment operations.

Comment: best/worst/average O here is O(N), where N is the length of input, no matter how many increments inside of loop - it is constant/fixed

Comment: Why are you passing `nwhite` and `nother` as parameters to the `my_getchar()` function? Why would it need to know how many of those characters you've read previously?

Comment: You should use the built-in `isdigit()` and `iswhite()` functions.